# Existence of Equal Terms In Type Theory

Tags: logic, homotopy-theory, type-theory, lambda-calculus

I am trying to implement a simple type theory (typed lambda calculus with sums) like the one described in

[Extensional Normalisation and Type-Directed Partial Evaluation for Typed Lambda Calculus with Sums](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Empf23/papers/Types/tdpe.pdf)

It seems to me that adding the following rule to the system makes things simpler and more sensible:

$$\begin{array}{c}
\underline{\Gamma\vdash a\equiv a':A}\\
\Gamma\vdash a:A
\end{array}$$

But I am not sure if including this rule within the type theory is a good idea, and so I would like opinions about whether this rule can be added without causing logical issues.

The reason I want to add the above rule, is that some of the rules in the above reference introduce equal terms without declaring their types, and sometimes I seem to need to declare that such terms indeed have types, in order to do further operations upon them.

Comment: It would be extremely weird to *not* have this rule. I'm sure that the paper tacitly assumes that the equality judgment only involves well-typed sides.

Comment: (This judgment usually means that both sides have type $A$)

Comment: Thanks. I thought it made sense. I must say I find it remarkable how much many papers about type theory assume rules they don't spell out. I thought the point was to be formal. Anyway, it was very helpful of you to verify that this is a rule.